# Function with lists/scalars as arguments

Tags: python, numpy

If I define a function as:

```
def somefunc(a, b, c):
    out = [ (a+b)/c for a, b, c in zip(a, b, c) ]
    return out
```

all the arguments must be lists of the same length, otherwise I would get the output truncated. Example: `somefunc([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 5])` would give me `[0.8, 1.2]`.

It would be really convenient to be able to input a single number instead of a list when it doesn't change, like: `somefunc([1, 2], [3, 4], 5)`. Of course any of the arguments can be reduced to a single value instead of a list. This can be achieved using numpy with this function definition:

```
from numpy import array

def somefunc(a, b, c):

    a=array(a)
    b=array(b)
    c=array(c)

    out = (a+b)/c
    return out
```

Is there a way to do the same without numpy (and without converting all the arguments one by one)?

Comment: No, `zip` expects iterable arguments; if your function takes non-iterable arguments, you will have to convert them.

Comment: Note: If you want NumPy features, the easiest way is going to be to use NumPy. Each feature can of course be implemented without NumPy, but if that was easy, NumPy wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can make an infinite list repeating any argument that is not a list in itself.

```
from itertools import repeat

def broadcast(o):
    return o if hasattr(o, '__iter__') else repeat(o)

def somefunc(a, b, c):
    out = [ (a+b)/c for a, b, c in zip(broadcast(a), broadcast(b), broadcast(c)) ]
    return out

>>> somefunc([1, 2], [3, 4], 5)
[0.8, 1.2]
>>> somefunc([1, 2], 5, [3, 4])
[2.0, 1.75]
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't work if the scalar argument is not the last: `somefunc([1, 2], 3, [5, 5])`

Comment: I think you commented the wrong answer. rroowwllaanndd's solution does not work if either of the first two arguments are scalars. Mine does.

Comment: ooops you are right, but now the other has been edited and it works as well. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is awesome, and is perfect for vectorizing computaions like the one you posted. I'd recommend you *do* use it.

Also, you don't need to convert all the arguments to arrays, only one, and it is better to use `asarray`, which would avoid creating a new copy when one isn't necessary.

```
def somefunc(a, b, c):
    return (asarray(a) + b) / c
```